# Given a layer of counties and a layer of roads, summarize the total mileage of roads by road name

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, line

Given a road layer and a county layer. I need to know the mileage of roads by road name in each county.

How can I do that?

Comment: Are you a python user?

Comment: I am a newbie for python. Know a little bit.

Comment: intersect, dissolve by county name and within that dissolve tool add field and calculate sum of shape area

Answer (score 1):

Look at this question :
[Calculating line segment lengths within polygon using ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/52240/calculating-line-segment-lengths-within-polygon-using-arcgis-desktop)

and this one :
[Calculate line distances inside of polygons using ArcGIS for Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/98518/calculate-line-distances-inside-of-polygons-using-arcgis-for-desktop)

Both of them have good answers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have looked at them before I posted the question but I will take a closer look.

Comment: I think both of them want the total line length within a polygon which is different. My question is to calculate the percentage of each line record within each of those polygons that intersected...

Comment: Then a work around will be: to get the lengths of the lines that intersected the polygons in column, get the overall length of the lines in another column and then you can work out the percentage!

Comment: Not really. I have many line records and each one of them need to do the analysis separately. In your method, I will need to use each line record as a separate layer in order to do that..that is impossible for me to run the anlaysis

Comment: Using either Union or Intersect, with the source line length as an attribute in the line table is the canonical solution.

Comment: I used real example to show the question..